# MSAccess: Null vs '' - driving me crazy

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with 2 embedded subforms.

The on-click event on subform_1 sets the recordsource of subform_2 referencing 5 attrs from the selected subform_1 record (all TEXT fields).

```
strSQL = "SELECT Table_1.* FROM Table_1 " & _
    "WHERE (((Table_1.Attr_A)= '" & Forms![mainform]![subform_1]![attr1] & "') " & _
    "AND ((Table_1.Attr_B) = '" & Forms![mainform]![subform_1]![attr2] & "') " & _
    "AND ((Table_1.Attr_C) = '" & Forms![mainform]![subform_1]![attr3] & "') " & _
    "AND ((Table_1.Attr_D) = '" & Forms![mainform]![subform_1]![attr4] & "') " & _
    "AND ((Table_1.Attr_E) = '" & Forms![mainform]![subform_1]![attr5] & "'));"
Forms![mainform]![subform_2].Form.RecordSource = strSQL
```

My issue is that some records may have a NULL value among the 5 required attrs, which is a valid condition.  The surrounding '' when the subform_1 value is NULL is resulting in (0) records in the collection.

Any suggestions to effectively handle the NULL condition in subform_1?

Comment: can you just use `OR IS NULL` for each attr that could be NULL?

Comment: Thanks, This gets me close, but returns the valid condition where all 5 Attrs are null with EACH permutation of Null and Not Null attr data.

Comment: @Joe T is right, you need to make the WHERE clause look like:
Where (Attr_A = 'xyz' or Attr_A Is Null) AND (Attr_B = 'abc' or Attr_B Is Null) .....

Comment: Just saw your follow-up.. If it is not acceptable to return rows if all 5 fields are null, then you need another test to check if all are null.

Comment: Your code has a huge SQL injection security vulnerability. Always escape user-entered data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were considering only `Table_1.Attr_A`, I think you're saying you want this ...

```vb
"SELECT t1.* FROM Table_1 AS t1 " & _
"WHERE (t1.Attr_A & '') = '" & Forms![mainform]![subform_1]![attr1] & "'"
```

If that is correct, add an `AND` for the next condition based on `Attr_B`.

```vb
"SELECT t1.* FROM Table_1 AS t1 " & _
"WHERE " & _
"(t1.Attr_A & '') = '" & Forms![mainform]![subform_1]![attr1] & "'" & _
" AND (t1.Attr_B & '') = '" & Forms![mainform]![subform_1]![attr2] & "'"
```

And continue from there by adding the remaining conditions.

Comment: HansUp - been looking at this for too long.  Your solution DOES return the records with NULL Attr Values@   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Nz` function can also be of use:

```
"SELECT t1.* FROM Table_1 AS t1 " & _
"WHERE Nz(t1.Attr_A) = '" & Forms![mainform]![subform_1]![attr1] & "'"
```